# How do I open and edit a Microsoft Word document file without Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, openoffice

I have downloaded a Microsoft Word (.docx) file which was created using a template.

I want to open and edit it but I have not installed Microsoft Word in my computer (I am using Windows 10 by the way).

Instead I create and edit document files with OpenOffice Document (.odt). Can anyone suggest how I can open and edit my .docx file without losing the format, either through OpenOffice or an online available tool?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: OpenOffice supports the `docx` format.

Comment: I agree with harrymc, you should be able to open and edit a .docx file in OpenOffice. Will it be the same? Maybe. You can also edit in Word Online, which is a browser app and free. By the way, I changed your question to remove the word template. That is misleading. In Word, a .docx file is never a template. Here is my page on templates: https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm For English usage, the file may well be a template, but not in Word usage.

Answer (score 0):

A few alternative approaches that you may want to try:

1. [ONLYOFFICE](https://www.onlyoffice.com/) : This one tries to work as similarly to Microsoft Office suite and should have the least formatting problems. The off-side is that it doesn't have most of the advanced features that MS Office has.

   - Recommend using this only when you absolutely need to work with MS Office. For everything else, use [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)
2. [Google Docs](https://www.google.com/docs/about/) : If you don't mind having your data on the cloud, this is usable.

   - I tried the equivalent for PowerPoint presentations and it greatly changes the formatting from .docx
3. [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) : I recommend using LibreOffice instead of OpenOffice everywhere, simply because it started from OpenOffice (OpenOffice hasn't seen any proper development in years, other than some typo fixes in code) and has way more features, along with multiple interface choices.

   - This should work slightly better than OpenOffice for .docx